# Mysql Sorted items by user get an overall order

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

I have a list of films that users can rank in order of which they like best using jQuery UI Sortable (all works well). The lower the order number the better the film (1) and the higher (26) the worse it is. The list of films could be endless but is fixed in the database (users can't add more), so the user can only select from x list of films.

Films do not have to be in the users list, if they haven't seen film 5 then it won't get included (this may be compounding the problem).

Currently this is stored in the table:

```
film_id | user_id | order
4         2         3
5         3         3
6         2         1
7         2         2
7         3         1 
8         3         2
```

What I want, and don't know where to start is an overall 'Top 10' style list. i.e. film 7 is the most popular because it appears higher up peoples lists and is in more lists. Film 6 could be the most popular but it's only in one list?!

I am stuck on both the logic and the Mysql queries to do it!

I am thinking I might need to weight the order somehow? Or have a separate table with the score per film and just update it after every edit. The following query seems like the right idea if it was just based on the count of items in the table but not when I want to add position in to the equation.

```
SELECT ff.film_id, COUNT(ff.film_id) AS cnt, SUM(ff.order) AS rank FROM
`favourite_film` AS ff GROUP BY ff.film_id ORDER BY cnt DESC, rank ASC
```

I guess I need the count of all the films in the table and the sum of the order (but reversed?), my theory then goes flat!

Any help or links would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think I would "flip" the values of the rankings, so that #1 would have the highest value (say 3 or 10 or whatever), then have the lower ranked movies have lower values.  Than I would just sum the values and rank by the total descending.  That would take into popularity and the rankings.

Comment: This was what I should of done originally and not even needed the post! I may fall back to this but I like Sylvians answer. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending your "business rules", I think you should find some sort of calculation to both take into account the position *and* the number of "votes".

Just a random guess, but why not sorting by `COUNT(votes)/AVG(pos)` ? For maintainability reason, you might want to factor out the *ranking* function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ranking(average_pos REAL, vote_count INT)
RETURNS REAL
DETERMINISTIC
  RETURN vote_count/average_pos;
```

The query is now simply:

```
SELECT film_id,
       AVG(pos) as a, COUNT(*) as c, ranking(AVG(pos),COUNT(*)) AS rank
  FROM vote GROUP BY film_id
  ORDER BY ranking(AVG(pos), COUNT(*)) DESC;
```

Producing with your example:

```
+----------+------+----+----------------+
| FILM_ID  |  A   | C  |      RANK      |
+----------+------+----+----------------+
|       7  | 1.5  | 2  | 1.333333333333 |
|       6  | 1    | 1  | 1              |
|       8  | 2    | 1  | 0.5            |
|       5  | 3    | 1  | 0.333333333333 |
|       4  | 3    | 1  | 0.333333333333 |
+----------+------+----+----------------+
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b1d9/1

Answer (score 0):

you should have reverted the list before saving it. this way you could leave the unselected movies out of the rating.

a workaround might be:

Count the amount of lists `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)` save this as `$AMOUNT_OF_LISTS`

now count the points using

```
SELECT film_id, (SUM(order)+($AMOUNT_OF_LISTS-COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id)))*POINTS_FOR_NOT_IN_LIST) as points FROM table GROUP BY film_id
```

logic: sum up all points and add `POINTS_FOR_NOT_IN_LIST` points for every time not in a list (total amount of lists - amount of times movie is in the list)

insert a value `POINTS_FOR_NOT_IN_LIST` to your liking. (might be 26 or 27 or even lower)

you probably want to add `ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10` to the query to get 10 highest points

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(  `order` ) , COUNT( * ) AS cnt,  `film_id` 
FROM  `favourite_film` 
GROUP BY  `film_id` 
ORDER BY cnt DESC ,  `order`
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this, I would assign a higher value to the movies with the higher ranking.  Then I would sum the values per movie and order by the total descending to get the overall ranking.  This way you are giving weight to both the popularity and rankings of each movie.

So if you wanted to do it by the top 3 ranked movies per user you could do this:

```
SELECT  film_id, SUM(3         -- The max number of ranked movies per user
                     - order   -- the ranking
                     + 1) total_score

FROM    TABLE_NAME

GROUP BY film_id

ORDER BY total_score DESC;
```

Obviously you could remove the comments

This way the top rated movie would get the higher score, the next highest, the next highest score, etc.  If you were counting the top 10 movies per user, just change the 3 to 10.